# Throws exception when i try to color the text box in WPF

Tags: wpf

I was trying to set grey color to my text box.I was trying to do the following code but it  is throwing an exception  as

**"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."**

because the text box value is null but I want the text box to be in grey color irrespective of the value present or absent.

Here is the code I used to implement the concept..

```
 <TextBox
    Name="tbHeadline" 
    Text="{Binding SelectedStory.Headline, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource ErrorTemplate}" 
    Grid.Column="1"  
    Grid.Row="6" 
    TextWrapping="NoWrap" 
    d:LayoutOverrides="Height" 
    Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
    LostFocus="tbHeadline_LostFocus" 
 />
```

Here is the code I used in Xaml.Cs

```
 tbHeadline.Foreground = Brushes.Gray;
```

I tried the following code also

```
tbHeadline.Background = Brushes.Gray;
```

Both throw the same excepiton.

Comment: Where in the code are you attempting to set the color? E.g. constructor?

Comment: am trying to set the color in xaml.cs,i have a condition,if the condition met then i change the color of the text box.

Comment: yes, **where** in this xaml.cs file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XAML elements are created during the code-behind's `InitializeComponent` method so if you're attempting to access a named element before that call it will be `null`.

Comment: Thanks @John Bowen, i gotcha what you mean,so there is no way i can change the background color before it get intialize ?,even i tried this option "if(tbHeadline.SelectedText.Trim().Length !=0)" its not working either

Comment: If you're putting the code in the constructor, just move it to after InitializeComponent. Initialization of the controls is not the same thing as display. A bunch of other steps happen before they show up on the screen so you're not going to get the wrong color showing up and then changing.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you set the property directly in the XAML markup file? If you do not want to do in XAML file, i would suggest (i usually do it this way):

1. In the constructor, setup event handler for Loaded event of the whole page or control
2. Set your initial values for control inside the event handler

Example: 
    this.Loaded += (sender, e) => {
    tbHeadline.Background = Brushes.Gray;
    }